# Error Running SparkApp local or YARN

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

At the moment we got the problem, that submitting a spark app with --master local[*] and --master yarn leads to different behaviours. A local submitted application runs fine, starting it on yarn leads - after the first 5 to 7 stages - to the following error:

```
 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 210, quickstart.cloudera): java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_8_piece0 of broadcast_8
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1177)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_8_piece0 of broadcast_8
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1174)
    ... 11 more

[Stage 7:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 2]16/07/22 07:34:53 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
16/07/22 07:34:53 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting job.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 7.0 (TID 214, quickstart.cloudera): java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_8_piece0 of broadcast_8
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1177)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_8_piece0 of broadcast_8
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1174)
    ... 11 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1294)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1282)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1281)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1281)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1507)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1469)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1824)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1837)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1914)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:325)
    at dataCreator.DataSetGenerator$$anonfun$createVP$1.apply(DataSetGenerator.scala:160)
    at dataCreator.DataSetGenerator$$anonfun$createVP$1.apply(DataSetGenerator.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at dataCreator.DataSetGenerator$.createVP(DataSetGenerator.scala:144)
    at dataCreator.DataSetGenerator$.generateDataSet(DataSetGenerator.scala:78)
    at runDriver$.main(runDriver.scala:14)
    at runDriver.main(runDriver.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_8_piece0 of broadcast_8
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1177)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_8_piece0 of broadcast_8
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1174)
    ... 11 more
16/07/22 07:34:53 ERROR DefaultWriterContainer: Job job_201607220734_0000 aborted.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:325)
    at dataCreator.DataSetGenerator$$anonfun$createVP$1.apply(DataSetGenerator.scala:160)
    at dataCreator.DataSetGenerator$$anonfun$createVP$1.apply(DataSetGenerator.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at dataCreator.DataSetGenerator$.createVP(DataSetGenerator.scala:144)
    at dataCreator.DataSetGenerator$.generateDataSet(DataSetGenerator.scala:78)
    at runDriver$.main(runDriver.scala:14)
    at runDriver.main(runDriver.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 7.0 (TID 214, quickstart.cloudera): java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_8_piece0 of broadcast_8
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1177)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_8_piece0 of broadcast_8
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1174)
    ... 11 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1294)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1282)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1281)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1281)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1507)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1469)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1824)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1837)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1914)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_8_piece0 of broadcast_8
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1177)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_8_piece0 of broadcast_8
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1174)
    ... 11 more
```

We guess this should be the interesting part of the code. When the method *handleTypes* isn't called. The app runs without the error as well.

```
/**
   * Generates VP table for each unique predicate in input RDF dataset.
   * All tables have to be cached, since they are used for generation of ExtVP 
   * tables.
   */
  private def createVP() = {    
    // create directory for all vp tables
    Helper.removeDirInHDFS(Settings.vpDir)
    Helper.createDirInHDFS(Settings.vpDir)
    StatisticWriter.initNewStatisticFile("VP")

    // create and cache vpTables for all predicates in input RDF dataset
    for (predicate <- _uPredicates){      
      var vpTable = _sqlContext.sql("select sub, obj "
                                  + "from triples where pred='"+predicate+"'")          

      val cleanPredicate = Helper.getPartName(predicate)

      // --> without this call no error occurs <-- 
      vpTable = handleTypes(vpTable, predicate)


      vpTable.registerTempTable(cleanPredicate)
      _sqlContext.cacheTable(cleanPredicate)
      _vpTableSizes(predicate) = vpTable.count()

      //vpTable.saveAsParquetFile(Settings.vpDir + cleanPredicate + ".parquet")
      vpTable.write.parquet(Settings.vpDir + cleanPredicate + ".parquet")

      // print statistic line
      StatisticWriter.incSavedTables()
      StatisticWriter.addTableStatistic("<" + predicate + ">", 
                                        -1, 
                                        _vpTableSizes(predicate))

      writeLoadScript(Settings.vpDir + cleanPredicate + ".parquet", cleanPredicate, "", vpTable)
    }

    StatisticWriter.closeStatisticFile()
  }


  private def handleTypes(vTable: DataFrame, predIn: String) = {

        var pred = predIn
        //println("'" + pred + "'")

        if(pred.startsWith("<") && pred.endsWith(">")) {
          pred = pred.substring(1, pred.length() - 1)
        }

        var newSchema = StructType( StructField("sub", StringType, false) :: StructField("obj", StringType, false) :: Nil)
        var predType = ""

        // type check of object
        if(integerPred.contains(pred)) {
            newSchema = StructType( StructField("sub", StringType, false) :: StructField("obj", IntegerType, true) :: Nil)
            predType = "int"
        }else if (doublePred.contains(pred)) {
            newSchema = StructType( StructField("sub", StringType, false) :: StructField("obj", DoubleType, false) :: Nil)
            predType = "double"
        }else if (datePred.contains(pred)) {
            newSchema = StructType( StructField("sub", StringType, false) :: StructField("obj", DateType, false) :: Nil)
            predType = "date"
        }else if (dateTimePred.contains(pred)) {
            newSchema = StructType( StructField("sub", StringType, false) :: StructField("obj", TimestampType, false) :: Nil)
            predType = "timestamp"
        }

        var newRdd = vTable.rdd
        newRdd = newRdd.map( r => extractObj(r, predType))
        var newDF = _sqlContext.createDataFrame(newRdd, newSchema)
        newDF
  }

    private def extractObj(r: Row, predType: String) = {

        var pattern = new Regex("(?<=\").*?(?=\")")
        var obj = r.getString(1)
        var result = obj

        if(obj.contains("^^")) {
            result = pattern.findFirstIn(obj).get
            if(predType.equals("timestamp")){
              result = result.replace("T", " ")
            }
        }

        var result2 = Row(r.getString(0), result)

        if(predType.equals("int")){
          val ret = result.toInt
          result2 = Row(r.getString(0), ret)
        }else if(predType.equals("double")){
          val ret = result.toDouble
          result2 = Row(r.getString(0), ret)
        }else if(predType.equals("date")){
          val ret = getDate(result)
          result2 = Row(r.getString(0), ret)
        }else if(predType.equals("timestamp")){
          val ret = getTimestamp(result)
          result2 = Row(r.getString(0), ret)
        }

    result2
    }

    def getDate(x:Any) :java.sql.Date = {
    val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    if (x.toString() == "") 
    return null
    else {
        val d = format.parse(x.toString());
        val t = new Date(d.getDate());
        return t
    }
  }

    def getTimestamp(x:Any) :java.sql.Timestamp = {
    val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss")
    if (x.toString() == "") 
    return null
    else {
        val d = format.parse(x.toString());
        val t = new Timestamp(d.getTime());
        return t
    }
  }

  def writeLoadScript(path: String, tableName: String, relType: String, table: DataFrame) = {
  var relationType = relType.toUpperCase
  var columnList = table.schema.toSeq
  var subType = columnList(0).dataType.simpleString
  var objType = columnList(1).dataType.simpleString
  val fw = new java.io.FileWriter(_loadScriptName, true)
    try {
      if(tableName == "triples") {
          fw.write("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS triples;\n")
          fw.write("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE triples (sub STRING, pred STRING, obj STRING)\n")
          fw.write("STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION \'${hiveconf:prepath}" + path + "\';\n\n")
        }else {
          fw.write("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + relationType + _delimiter + tableName + ";\n")
          fw.write("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE " + relationType + _delimiter + tableName + " (sub " + subType + ", obj " + objType +")\n")
          fw.write("STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION \'${hiveconf:prepath}" + path + "\';\n\n")
        }
    }
    finally fw.close()




  }

  def initLoadScript() = {
  val fw = new java.io.FileWriter(_loadScriptName, false)
    try {
      fw.write("-- Hive 1.2.0 or later is needed! \n")
    }
    finally fw.close()

  }
```

We run this on Spark 1.6.1 and Hadoop 2.7.1 as well as on the Cloudera Quickstart VM with version 1.5.0-cdh5.5.2 and 2.6.0-cdh5.5.2. If you have any suggestions where to look at, let us know!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error is related to this open spark issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5594

As recommended in this [post](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5594?focusedCommentId=14581269&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14581269) of the issue, we serialized the function *extractObj*, the code now looks like that:

```
object FunctionSerializable extends Serializable{

  def extractObj(r: Row, predType: String): Row = {

        var pattern = new Regex("(?<=\").*?(?=\")")
        var obj = r.getString(1)
        var result = obj

        if(obj.contains("^^")) {
            result = pattern.findFirstIn(obj).get
            if(predType.equals("timestamp")){
              result = result.replace("T", " ")
            }
        }

        var result2 = Row(r.getString(0), result)

        if(predType.equals("int")){
          val ret = result.toInt
          result2 = Row(r.getString(0), ret)
        }else if(predType.equals("double")){
          val ret = result.toDouble
          result2 = Row(r.getString(0), ret)
        }else if(predType.equals("date")){
          val ret = getDate(result)
          result2 = Row(r.getString(0), ret)
        }else if(predType.equals("timestamp")){
          val ret = getTimestamp(result)
          result2 = Row(r.getString(0), ret)
        }

    result2
    }

    def getDate(x:Any) :java.sql.Date = {
    val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    if (x.toString() == "") 
    return null
    else {
        val d = format.parse(x.toString());
        val t = new Date(d.getDate());
        return t
    }
  }

    def getTimestamp(x:Any) :java.sql.Timestamp = {
    val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss")
    if (x.toString() == "") 
    return null
    else {
        val d = format.parse(x.toString());
        val t = new Timestamp(d.getTime());
        return t
    }
  }
}
```

The call in *handleTypes* looks like that:

```
newRdd = newRdd.map( r => FunctionSerializable.extractObj(r, predType))
```

And everything is working fine... :-)